# Matrices matching

Tags: r, matching

I have two matrices, `t1` and `t2`:

```
> t1
     aaa bbb ccc ddd
[1,]   1   2   3   4


> t2
     e1    e2    e3    e4    e5    e6    e7    e8    e9   
[1,] "aaa" "ddd" "aaa" "bbb" "ccc" "bbb" "ddd" "aaa" "ccc"
```

Is there a way to obtain a matrix that replaces the data of `t2` according to the table `t1` without a loop? The matrix I would like to have at the end is:

```
> t3
     e1 e2 e3 e4 e5 e6 e7 e8 e9
[1,]  1  4  1  2  3  2  4  1  3
```

I tried with the `%in%` matching, but as the two matrices have not the same length of course it doesn't work.

Comment: BladeVsResiduals, if one of the answers meets your needs, please "accept" it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the matching

```
t(setNames(t1[1,][t2[1,]], colnames(t2)))
#     e1 e2 e3 e4 e5 e6 e7 e8 e9
#[1,]  1  4  1  2  3  2  4  1  3
```

---

For multiple rows of 't2' (based on the example in @r2evans post)

```
out <- `dim<-`(t1[1,][t2], dim(t2))
colnames(out) <- colnames(t2)
out
#     e1 e2 e3 e4 e5 e6 e7 e8 e9
#[1,]  1  4  1  2  3  2  4  1  3
#[2,]  1  4  1  2  3  2  4  1  3
```

#### data

```
t1 <- t(setNames(1:4, strrep(letters[1:4], 3)))
t2 <- t(setNames(strrep(c('a', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'a', 'c'), 
            3), paste0("e", 1:9)))
```

Comment: For curiosity, that fails if `t2` has multiple rows.

Comment: @r2evans `m = matrix(t1[1,][t2], nrow(t2), dimnames=dimnames(t2))`?

Comment: @r2evans It is not clear whether both matrices have multiple rows or one.  Anyway, as @Frank showed, it can be converted to a `matrix` after doing the matrching

Answer (score 1):

For grins, I added a second row to `t2`:

```
t1 <- as.matrix(read.table(header=TRUE, row.names=1, text='
     aaa bbb ccc ddd
[1,]   1   2   3   4'))
t2 <- as.matrix(read.table(header=TRUE, row.names=1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text='
     e1    e2    e3    e4    e5    e6    e7    e8    e9   
[1,] "aaa" "ddd" "aaa" "bbb" "ccc" "bbb" "ddd" "aaa" "ccc"
[2,] "ddd" "ddd" "aaa" "bbb" "ccc" "bbb" "ddd" "aaa" "ccc"'))

array(t1[1,][t2], dim=dim(t2), dimnames=dimnames(t2))
#      e1 e2 e3 e4 e5 e6 e7 e8 e9
# [1,]  1  4  1  2  3  2  4  1  3
# [2,]  4  4  1  2  3  2  4  1  3
```

(I had tried `t2[] <- t1[1,][t2]`, but because `t2` is originally a `character` matrix, the indices are converted:

```
t2a <- t2
t2a[] <- t1[1,][t2]
t2a
#      e1  e2  e3  e4  e5  e6  e7  e8  e9 
# [1,] "1" "4" "1" "2" "3" "2" "4" "1" "3"
# [2,] "4" "4" "1" "2" "3" "2" "4" "1" "3"
```

)